# Font awesome html side not working

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I've been using Font Awesome for a while now. But just recently I figured that my icons that are html based don't load. They show themselves as a square. Can you please help me. I've also written down the code right below:

```
<!-- source -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Code in the body -->
<li  class="icon1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg icon small-margin"></i></a></li>
<li  class="icon2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg icon small-margin"></i></a></li>
<li  class="icon3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss fa-lg icon small-margin"></i></a></li>
```

Please note: only the code I've written above does not work but the code below works fine.

```
.search:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f002';
  background: #21a1e1;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-smooth: always;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0v84bLtu - everything loads fine.

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried using a protocol relative link: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`? Your issue may be an http/https conflict.

Comment: Could be a case of bad internet. I have seen it happen before.

Comment: Also, server or client-side caching can cause icons to show as squares. I have run into that in production sites.

Comment: None of your suggestions worked. :(, thanks anyways though

Comment: can you add your classes for the icons

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xecawekoje

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xecawekoje/edit?html,css

Comment: The way you have them it seems like they are seen as image elements rather than text. Technically it is a series of images acting like a font so try removing font awesome as a font family from the above css in your post. If not, have you used import or @font rule to declare font awesome as a font family? If not, css won't recognize it as a font family. Also because      you have the character listed in the css and the html, the two could be competing .

Comment: Thank you CHoltzman that fixed it!!!. Thumbs up for you m8.